# Using Django select_related across multiple Databases

Tags: python, django, orm, multiple-databases

I have two database connections in the Django project, below is the Database settings:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'mysql_db_name',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysql_db_pass',
        'HOST': 'localost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'postgres_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgresql_db_name',
        'USER': 'postgresql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgresql_db_pass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
```

And these are models:

```
# sales/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User # Django's auth user model this is in MySQL

class Batch(models.model):     # this table is in PostgreSQL
    class params:
        db = 'postgres_db'
    created_by = ForeignKeyAcrossDb(User, db_constraint=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

`ForeignKeyAcrossDb` is working fine which is inherited from `models.Foreignkey`.
Foreignkey across multiple databases is working as expected, this is not an issue, my concern is using `select_related()`.

If I run the ORM
`data = Batch.objects.filter(created_by=request.user.pk)` it works fine.

But I want to run this ORM using select_related() like this

```
data = Batch.objects.select_related('created_by').filter(created_by=request.user.pk)
```

This gives an error

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "auth_user" does not exist
LINE 1: ...r"."date_joined" FROM "sales_batch" INNER JOIN "auth_user...
```

Which is pretty obvious as `auth_user` is in MySQL and `select_related()` is looking in PostgreSQL for the `join` to work.

How can I use `select_related()` spanning multiple databases?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't: `.select_related` makes `JOIN`. This thus means that the two should have the same database...

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? What if I could modify `select_related()` to use database names in the SQL. As far as I know, `JOIN` can work in multiple databases (not really tried it but read it somewhere).